# Diskspd or HammerDB for SQL Server disk IO performance testing

Tags: sql-server, io, benchmarking, disk

We've evaluating a a possible addition to our virtualized SQL Server environment.  I have to test disk IO and have been looking at DISKSPD and quite happy with it.  I just ran with the accelator cards enabled and the performance was significantly degraded.

The vendor stated the synthetic workload wasn't a good test of the system and suggested HammerDB.  HammerDB doesn't seem to give the same control and requires a lot more moving parts to capture the same data.

Anyone with an opinion one way or the other?

Comment: It depends on what you want to test.  DiskSpd is great for isolated performance testing of the storage subsystem and I/O stack.  I use it whenever commissioning a new server to ensure the storage is performing to specs.  HammerDB (or similar tool) is better for testing the DBMS configuration.

Comment: Thanks.  It's a proof of concept on whether PernixData cards/software will help our SQL Performance.  The thing is most of our databases see latency of 15-25 ms without it.  Don't know how we can get much better.

Comment: Is that disk latency measured with PMON or end-to-end from the app side?  That seems quite high for an OLTP query that returns a few rows, but not so much if the query is complex and/or returns many rows.

Comment: That's the results from Diskspd.  I went ahead and installed SQL and or monitoring tools.  Ran the HammerDB with a large workload for our environment and got reads of 1 ms and writes of 2 ms on tempdb and 7 and 1 on the tpcc database with dm_io_virtual_file_stats with a snapshot taken before the test started and right after it finsihed.

Comment: I'm think the 15-25 ms from Diskspd is a pretty extreme load that's pushing the disk to high utilization.  The performance tab in VSphere is seeing a good bit of activity.